# Struggling with nested for loops

Tags: java, loops, nested

Alright so, I'm new to nested for loops adn I'm having a bit of an issue on understanding them. I've read many guides, but I still don't fully understand.

Alright the prompt:

Write nested for loops that produce the following output:

000111222333444555666777888999
000111222333444555666777888999
000111222333444555666777888999

What I have so far

```
for(int num2 = 0; num2 <= 9;  num2++) {

      for(int num1 = 0; num1 <= 2; num1++) {

            System.out.println(num2 + " " + num2 + " " + num2);
      }
}
```

And the output is

0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
2 2 2
2 2 2
2 2 2
3 3 3
3 3 3
3 3 3
4 4 4
4 4 4
4 4 4
5 5 5
5 5 5
5 5 5
6 6 6
6 6 6
6 6 6
7 7 7
7 7 7
7 7 7
8 8 8
8 8 8
8 8 8
9 9 9
9 9 9
9 9 9

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to use the loop counters together for this (e.g. `j < i`).  Taking that route is not only unnecessary but also probably what is hurting your head. :}

Answer (score 3):

You got 3 copies of each number.

the outer loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

chooses which number you want to print so that is fine.

The inner loop however is comparing j against the chosen number. You want 3 copies, not a variable number of copies. This change will make 3 copies:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
```

You also don't need this:

```
System.out.println(i);
```

EDIT: I just noticed you need 3 of these outputs.

add an outer loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
```

and a blank space

```
System.out.println(" ");
```

So the final result should be:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 3; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Comment: No problem. Mark as answer to make the question answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            System.out.print(j + "" + j + "" + j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the program provided by you the following events take place:-

1. In first loop variable i is initiated, condition for loop is checked and then it moves to the second loop if condition is true.
2. Now second loop iterates over the value of j until the condition is false and then control returns to the first loop.

Try to follow the working of loop and you can see yourself where were you wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

- loop 1:  You want the sequence 3 times, each occurrence on its own line.
- loop 2:  You want the sequence to have digits 0 through 9 ascendingly.
- loop 3:  You want the sequence to have each digit in succession 3 times.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int k = 0; k<3, k++){
    for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <  3;j++) {

            System.out.println(i);   
        }
        }
        System.out.println("")};

    }
    }
```

Comment: This could do with a bit of context and commentary, rather than just a code snippet

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int k=0;k<3;k++) {  
   for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j <  3;j++) {
            System.out.println(i);   
        }
    }
}
```

Although I am by far most inexperienced guy here, I think this should give exact output you're looking for.

Comment: Does not print the space.